# SDL_SetColorKey doesn't set the background transparent

Tags: c, image, transparency, sdl

it comes down to this code:

```
SDL_Surface *smiley = SDL_LoadBMP("./images/smileys/normal_up.bmp");
printf("Transparation worked: %i\n", SDL_SetColorKey(smiley, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, SDL_MapRGB(smiley->format, 255, 0, 255)));
SDL_BlitSurface(smiley, NULL, window, NULL);
SDL_Flip(window);
```

This is the [image](http://picturepush.com/public/12136938) I used.
Using SDL on Arch Linux.

Comment: Your exact code works for me, must be something else then. Im using SDL 1.2 on win 7.       Does the picture appear at all?

Comment: Try using 32 bits per pixel in your `SDL_SetVideoMode()` call

Comment: Transparency works with any depth. Works even with 8 bpp because this isnt normal transparency but a special color set to be invisible.

Comment: Try saving your image as a 24 bit bitmap instead. The one you linked to appears to be 32 BPP. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973551/problems-with-sdl-setcolorkey

Comment: The image appears, just non-transparent. I'll try setting the BPP to 32

Comment: I now tried setting the BPP to 32 in SetVideoMode and used a jpg image (24bpp) instead of bmp. Both didn't work. The image always appears without transparency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines right before the SDL_SetColorKey()-call make the whole thing work:

```
smiley->format->Amask = 0xFF000000;
smiley->format->Ashift = 24;
```

Now I can use .bmp or .jpg files with 32 or 24 bpp VideoMode, everything works!
Don't know why, don't know how that works.